# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( error

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I seem to be getting an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`  and can't seem to understand why.

I am using a jquery and [typed.js](http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js/)

```
function username(){
        var usernametxt = "Username"
        var usernameBox
        function (){
              //Change Username Input Box to be selected. 
              var userBox = document.getElementById('svg').contentDocument.getElementById("userBox")
                    $(userBox).css('stroke','#0B00F7')

      usernameBox = document.getElementById('svg').contentDocument.getElementById("username")
      $(document.getElementById('svg').contentDocument.getElementById("username")).typed({
        strings: [usernametxt],
        typeSpeed: 30,
        callback: function(){
            var userBox = document.getElementById('svg').contentDocument.getElementById("userBox")
            $(userBox).css('stroke','#4D4D4D')
            password()
         }
      });
};
```

};

Comment: @scrowler: Semicolons are optional in JavaScript.

Comment: Why is there a `function () { }` in the middle of this (right after the `var username`)?

Comment: Are you sure `var usernameBox
        function (){` is syntactically correct?

Comment: I suggest using something like jshint to check your js code, it's a breeze to spot syntax error like unmatched '{', try pasting your code to http://www.jshint.com/ to see for yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

You defined an anonymous function

Either assign it to a variable or give it a name

`var f = function () { ... }`

or

`function f() { ... }`

Answer (score 1):

You have a function expression in a statement context. Specifically:

```
function() {
    // ...
}
```

You have to consider what you want to do with that function. Even if it were valid syntax, why would you ever want to construct a function and then discard it without doing anything with it? Presumably, you either meant to name it so you could reference it later:

```
function foo() {
    // ...
}
```

Or maybe you wanted to pass it as an argument to some other function:

```
bar(function() {
    // ...
});
```

But the way you’ve got it now, it’s a useless function expression appearing in a statement context, which just happens to be invalid syntax as well as useless.